# Jackson Deserialization of dynamic data fails,

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, jackson, jackson-databind

```
public class Baseproperties
{
@JsonProperty("id")
private String id ;
private Integer ccode;
//...set and geters
}


public class Person
{
@JsonProperty("name")
private String name ;
private Integer age;
@JsonProperty("props")
private Baseproperties bprop;
//...set and geters
}


public class Cars
{
@JsonProperty("model")
private String Model ;
private Integer yearOfMake;
@JsonProperty("props")
private Baseproperties bprop;
//...set and geters
}

public MessageWrapper
{
@JsonProperty("ct")
private String classType;
private Object data;
//...set and geters
}
```

I need to serialise MessageWrapper class to json, but the approach fails due to unable to desearialize the Object data;
here i am reading the classType and desearializing it to either Person or CarType

//Person
{
  "name": "arnold",
  "age": 21
}

//car
{
  "model": "Moriz",
  "yearOfMake": 1892
}

```
//example MessageWrapper
String s= "{
  "ct": "<packagename>.car",
  "data": {
      "model": "Moriz",
      "yearOfMake": 1892
      "props":{
      "id" : "12312",
      "ccode" :33
      }
    }

}"

mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
MessageWrapper mw = mapper.readValue(s, MessageWrapper.class);
if(mw.getclassType().toString().equals("<packagename>.car"))
Cars cw = mapper.readValue(mw.getData(), Cars.class);
but cw is wrong // serialise fails.
```

Comment: I do not think this is how you want to compare Strings here `mw.getclassType()=="<packagename>.car"`

Comment: @michalk edited, its just to show only, you can think as zuedo.

Answer (score 0):

This is because there is no `ObjectMapper::readValue` method that takes `Object` as first argument.

By default with your approach Jackson will deserialize your `data` field to `LinkedHashMap` because you have given it `Object` type.

To then deserialize this value manually you will have to use [`ObjectMapper::convertValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#convertValuejava.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Class) and passing `Cars.class` as argument :

```
Cars cw = mapper.convertValue(mw.getData(), Cars.class);
```

And also get rid of :

```
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
```

as it does not seem to be needed here.

And just to add, I am not sure that approach with such dynamic data is good because, if you will be creating more and more types of objects you will end up with a tower of `ifs` or colosal switch statement.